# How to detect a file tranfer is completed or not in ETL . from windows SFTP Server

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

> We have File like Zip, txt Files in Windows SFTP Server and we use Informatica for our ETL Jobs , but our concern is the vendors who drop Files in SFTP Server they drop files in random times ,  and the files are of different sizes so How can we detect a File transfer is complete or Not??

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't. When your client is asking the FTP server for a list of files, it receives the current state on the server. There's no way of telling if one of the files is currently being written to or not.

So the only way here is to work out some kind of protocol with the vendor. You would need to work with some kind of lock file. If the vendor is writing to the file, they first have to create the lock file. Same goes for your ETL job when reading the file, you would first have to create the lock file and the vendor is not allowed to start a new file writing process until the lock is removed. You get the idea.

It all depends on how fool prove the solution needs to be. Another option is to let the vendor write to a temporary file first. Only when the upload process is finished, they rename the file to its final name.

Answer (score 0):

Writing to temp file and renaming once write is complet is one option, as Socken23 indicated. Others might be:

- create empty .ready file once write to target file is done. Your process should then check for the existence of .ready file and read data from the other one.
- perform a sequence of file size checks on FTP before starting the ETL. E.g. check file size, wait one minute, check again, wait & check third time. If all sizes match, you may assume the write is complete.

Comment: [for large files usually it takes more than a day to complete so in that case the timer may be not a great option or for some reason if the transfer breaks and then it might restarted or network issues then there may be duplicate files right we want to eliminate that process , so currently we are removing those in etl after a couple of days ]

Comment: Ok. So in general it's not possible to detect if the transfer is complete. Best way would be to ask the Sender to drop some additional, empty indicator file and monitor this one. (1st option mentioned above)